# Pattern recognition in a bitstream

Tags: algorithm, pattern-recognition, bitstream

Assume a long bitstream of bits. I want to discover some patterns in this bitstream. What I know is that this bitstream is not a random bitstream and contains some repetitive pattern.

As an example, assume that the bitstream is as below:

```
010100000101000101010010010100110101...
```

There is a known pattern in this bitstream: some values are set between `0101`s. If we separate this bitstream 4 by 4 bits we will see that some values are set between some `0101` pattern.

```
0101 0000 0101 0001 0101 0010 0101 0011 0101...
```

Is there any way to find or recognize a pattern for values between `0101` or some other possible pattern?

Comment: What is the input and what is the expected output? The question as it stands is hard to understand. Please provide examples of what you are looking for.